# Can you use Git to track changes to VirtualBox disk?

Tags: configuration, virtual-machines, virtualbox, git, version-control

Can you track changes to a VirtualBox disk using a VCS like Git? If not what is a good way to use version control to track changes while configuring virtual servers.

**I understand that git doesn't track binary blobs very well.

I would like to mount the VirtualBox drive and track changes from the root. The only time I would have to worry about binary blobs would be the initial git commit and any git commit after I update a piece of software.

Comment: VCSes usually intender for tracking source files, i.e. small text files, not huge binary data. VirtualBox on the other hand could create snapshots of disk images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are much better off tracking changes inside the machine, as `git` etc. won't work very well with a large binary blob like a VM disk image.

To be able to roll back to another state, snapshots are an excellent solution, but they have a performance impact.

The best method (IMHO) is to use a configuration management tool (e.g. Puppet) and track the changes of it's config files.

Comment: What if I was to mount the VM disk and track changes (Using Git) for the entire root directory?

Comment: I ended up using ansible, but this answer put me down the right rabbit hole. Lots of options, its best to DYOR and find one that works with your dev style.